# iOS 5: Why doen't shadowopacity repeat animation work?

Tags: ios, ios5, calayer, shadow, cabasicanimation

I need to produce a glow effect around one of my imageviews. For that, I decided to use shadowopacity property.

Here is my code:

```
imageViewForAnimation.layer.position = viewOrigin;
imageViewForAnimation.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];
imageViewForAnimation.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
imageViewForAnimation.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0;
imageViewForAnimation.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
imageViewForAnimation.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
// Set up glow effect
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
anim.duration = 3.0;
anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim.autoReverses = YES;
[imageViewForAnimation.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];

imageViewForAnimation.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageViewForAnimation.bounds].CGPath;

imageViewForAnimation.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

However, animation just stops after running once. No repetition.
Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code on iOS 5 simulator, it works. Only problem there was capital "R" in

```
 anim.autoReverses= YES;
```

Correct code:

```
 anim.autoreverses= YES;
```

Incase you had correct spelling in your code, then problem might be in where you are adding the animation. As I said I just ran the code on iOS 5 simulator and works like charm.
Hope this helped

Comment: I had added this line here, but not in my code, that was the issue :-)...in any case you are right. Upvoted and marked correct. thanks!